# Expect Sidekiq Job to receive Async with arguments Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec-rails, sidekiq, rspec-sidekiq

I have the following Worker

```
class JobBlastingWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options queue: 'job_blasting_worker'

  def perform(job_id, action=nil)
    job = Job.find(job_id)

    JobBlastingService.new(job).call
  end
end
```

I also have the following `job_blasting_service`

```
class JobBlastingService
  def initialize(job)
    @job = job
  end

  def call
    ScoringWorker.perform_async(@job.id, 0, 'create')
  end
end
```

and in `scoring_worker`

```
class ScoringWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options queue: 'scoring_worker'

  def perform(job_id, version, action=nil)
    job = Job.find(job_id)

    job.version = version
    job.save
  end
end
```

Now i want to write an rspec test to verify that the arguments sent to the `ScoringWorker` is accurate.

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe JobBlastingWorker do
  before(:all) do
    Rails.cache.clear
  end

  describe 'perform' do
    context 'create' do
      it 'sends correct arguments for scoring worker' do
        @job = create(:job)
        expect(ScoringWorker).to receive(:perform_async).with(@job.id, 0, 'create').and_call_original
        worker = JobBlastingWorker.new
        expect(JobBlastingWorker).to receive(:perform_in)
        expect(ScoringWorker).to receive(:perform_async).exactly(1).times
        worker.perform(@job.id, 'create')
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I have this rspec test and when i run it, i get an error because it doesn't have any sidekiq job with the arguments.

How can i write this test for it to get the response needed

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to verify the arguments you sent are correct, something like this should get you close:

```
 subject(:job_blasting_worker) { described_class.perform_later(job_id, version, action) }

  let(:job) { create :job }

  it 'queues the job' do
    expect { job_blasting_worker }.to have_enqueued_job(described_class).with(
      job.id,
      0,
      'create'
    ).on_queue(if you have different queues)
  end
end
```

Comment: i dont want to do the verification like this.

Comment: and the test is for the ScoringWorker not the JobBlastingWorker